# passing complex type as param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular js / angular ui router 0.2.15

I am trying to pass complex js array into the controller using $state.go
Following is my code can you help. looks like following code throwing error

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=servicesProvider%20%3C-%20services

### .js file

```
var services = {complex type};
$state.go("linearOfferProcess", {'services': services});
```

### in my route.js

```
state('linearOfferProcess', {
            url: '/linearOfferProcessor',
            templateUrl: '/partials/linear_process.html',
            controller: 'linearProcessController',
            services:
                function($stateParams) {
                  return $stateParams.services;
                }
        }
```

### controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('linearOfferProcessController',function($scope) {

    $scope.services = services;

        });
```

Comment: state definition doesn't have `services` property in it..what you trying to achieve here..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know any possible of accomplishing this, but you could try doing it using a Factory. I made a small mockup for you, in the container I'm storing the services and creating a unique ID for every complex object. So you can retrieve it whenever you want.

```
angular.module('app').factory('ServicesContainer', function() {
    var counter = 1;
    return {
        container: {},
        add: function(services) {
            container[counter] = services;

            return counter;
        }
    };
});

angular.module('app').controller('SomeController', function(ServicesContainer, $state) {
    var id = ServicesContainer.add({ complex object });

    $state.go('services', {
        id: id
    });
});

angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider) {
   $stateProvider.state('services', {
        url: '/{id}',
        onEnter: function(ServicesContainer, $stateParams, $log) {
            $log.info('Services', ServicesContainer[$stateParams.id]);
        }
   });
});
```